# Python code to concat images and ts files using ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a folder with multiple `ts` files in it and I want to join the files by inserting an image for n number of duration between videos. Below is the list with the duration for which an image needs to be inserted for.

`['00:00:06:17', '00:00:00:16', '00:00:01:05', '00:00:00:31', '00:00:01:01']`
For example, if the folder has 5 `ts` files (this number might change so the folder needs to be iterable) then,

`video1 + image for 00:00:06:17 + video2 + image for 00:00:00:16 + video 3, etc...`

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

UPDATE:

```
for i in new_ts3:
    for m in filename[:-1]:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen (['ffmpeg', '-loop', '1', '-i', sys.argv[2], '-c:v', 'libx264', '-profile:v', 'high', '-t', i, '-pix_fmt', 'yuvj420p', '-vf', 'scale=1280:720', '-f', 'mpegts', '{}{}_.ts'.format((os.path.splitext(sys.argv[1]) [0]), m)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out1 = p1.communicate()
    break
```

where `new_ts3` is `['00:00:06:17', '00:00:00:16', '00:00:01:05', '00:00:00:31', '00:00:01:01']` and

`filename` is `['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', 'file5', 'file6']`

With the above, I am getting 5 files with different filenames but each file is of duration `00:00:06:17`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
i = 0
image_list = ['img1.jpeg', 'img2.jpeg'] 
duration = ['1200', '1300']


## First we make loops of images to videos with given duration
for i in range(len(image_list)):
    # change name according to whatever order you want to save the files format
    outname = image_list[i] + str(i) + '.mp4' 
    dur = duration[i]
    os.system(f'ffmpeg -loop 1 -i {images_list[i]} -c:v libx264 -t {dur} -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=320:240 {outname}')

# Then we onvert .mp4 files to .mpeg if not in .mpeg format as .mp4 files have headers
for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    if (filename.endswith(".mp4")):
        out_name = filename.split(".")[0] + str(.ts)
        os.system(f'ffmpeg -i filename -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts {out_name}')

## create a list of the order in which you want to combine files here
order_list = [] # create with your own logic
new_out = 'out.ts'
file_list = os.listdir(path)

for i in range(len(file_list)-1):
    new_out = 'out' + str(i) + '.ts'
    os.system(f'ffmpeg -i "concat:{file_list[i]}|{file_list[i+1]}" -c copy {new_out}')
    if (i+1 < len(file_list))
        file_list[i+1] = new_out
    else: 
        continue

## finally convert it to mp4 at the last step
```

- the flags used in commands are mostly self explanatory such as scale of output.
- In case of the last loop , we're simply updating the output file name every time by adding that to our file list and combining it with the next item in the list and pushing the output
- You can convert the final .ts file to any format of your choice. Look for FFMPEG documentation and to execute it in python use the os.system

Comment: so if I understand your code correctly, then you are taking some image files, converting them into ts files and then concatenating these image -> ts converted files?

Comment: correct. I'm converting the image files to ts first by looping them over the given time duration. then concatenating them in order after converting any mp4 files to intermediate ts format.

Comment: your code has certainly provided me an idea to achieve what I need. However, I have a list with filenames and each time I am creating a `ts` file with duration and trying to append each file with a filename from list, all the files being generated are of same duration. Please see the code I have updated,

Comment: solved. changed the code to `for i, m in zip(new_ts3, filename[:-1]):`

Comment: your code really helped but I cannot upvote due to my current reputation. Thanks again.